# Make button fill a percentage of a view

Tags: ios

Inside of a viewcontroller, I have a view that is the entire height of the viewcontroller, it is 150px wide, and its all the way to the left of the viewcontroller. I have 2 buttons inside the view that are the full 150px wide all of the time, but I want them to stack on top of each other, and each take up 50% of the height all of the time, no matter which device they are on. What constraints do I need to put on each of the buttons to make them do this, all in storyboard? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set up the top button so that leading, trailing, top, and height are all equal to the superview.  Set up the bottom button so that leading, trailing, bottom, and height are all equal to the superview.

Then edit the two height constraints and set the multipliers to 0.5.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the 0.5 multiplier part? What does the multiplier actually mean?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a definition for "multiply" that doesn't use the word "multiply" and failing.  :)  By setting the heights equal and then changing the multiplier to 0.5, you're saying make button_height equal to (view_height * 0.5).